# how to create iphone adhoc release for my client, i have client's apple dev account

Tags: iphone, ios, ios-provisioning, ad-hoc-distribution

This is my first app and apple's devel/distro profiles, certs, etc are eating my head for the last day. i could not figure out the requirements of them and how to do this obvious thing.

I developed an app for my client. They have a company account at apple. In that account they have added multiple devices too. Now i want to build the app for ad hoc distribution to test on those devices. They have given me their account login too.

Now i am stuck at what to do, (i have successfully added my developer account(nonpaid) to their team using the portal).. I tried many things which i cant even remember.. every time the xcode organizer shows 'invalid signing identity..' error.

Any helps would be thankful..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If they have created a development certificate already, you will need to get the private key from them.

If they have not, log in using THIER AppleID (for what you need to do it is not enough to be on the team).  Create a private key and upload it to get the development certificate from the provisioning portal.

Then with the development certificate sorted out, you can create an ad-hoc certificate (again you must be logged into the portal using the account they have, not your own).  Download that, install it in organizer.

Now in XCode4, you can run "Archive" with the "device" build selected.  After that you will get an archive in the organizer, from that you can select "share" and build an IPA to distribute.

Comment: yup, got the private keys, got it working although had to beat my head again on the entitlements.plist part finally. I think i need to study the code signing and provisioning in detail, the apple docs seems hard to follow. Can anyone point me to simple detail text/video?. Thanks.. :)

Comment: The need for the entitlements.plist was removed a while ago, I have not used it for years.  I don't have one at all.  I just make sure the signing is set up correctly for debug vs. release builds.

Comment: seems it is still needed for XCode versions less than 4

Answer (score 0):

Kendall is correct about the developer certificate.  The proper terminology for ad-hoc distribution is a PROVISIONING PROFILE (Kendall refers to as "ad-hoc certificate").  This is what ties the developer certificate to the list of devices (UDID's).  On iTunesConnect simply create a provisioning profile, download it, then install into your XCode project under Build Settings | Code Signing Identity | Release.  Then do the Build|Archive as described already.

Comment: Although it's a provisioning profile you can't just create any old profile, you have to create specifically an ad-hoc profile.  Thanks for the terminology correction, I tend to get a little loose between certificates and profiles.